# Android SQLITE FTS version

Tags: android, sqlite, full-text-search

I am using Android SQLITE FTS, but don't know which version is it?

How can I find if Android supports SQLITE FTS4 or FTS5?

I need to use custom stemming functions, which is only supported in FTS5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [compilation options](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html) for the SQLite library shipped with an Android can be chosen by the manufacturer when building the Android framework. And "can be chosen" means that nobody bothers to do so, so you always get the default, FTS4.

If you need anything else, you have to compile your own copy of the SQLite library with the NDK.